# Does monnayage refer to coin-making (minting) or manufacturing of money in general?

Tags: terminologie

Le titre est la question.

Does **monnayage** refer to coin-making (minting) or manufacturing of money in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary sense is minting, but since the invention of banknote, it has a wider sense. Exactly like “*frapper la monnaie*”  which is now both minting and printing, whereas we don't *frappe* banknotes literally.

Concerning *monnayage*, another common usage is figurative and means converting the value of something into money.

Answer (score 4):

*Monnayage* : "Fabrication de la monnaie à partir d'un métal ou d'un alliage monétaire.
*Faux monnayage* : fabrication de fausse monnaie." (Le Robert)

So it is only about coin-making

But : "Monnayable (adj) : que l'on peu monnayer, dont on peut tirer de l'argent" (Le Robert)
sound like English :  *able* to sell something to have some coins, or money in general.

Banknote are printable.

"*Monétaire* : Relatif à la monnaie" is used for banknote and coins, usually used as *Masse monétaire* in financial markets, politics : "SMI : Système Monétaire International". Abstract notion.

*Complément*
[Monnaie de PARIS](http://www.monnaiedeparis.fr/) est un établissement qui frappe encore les collections de pièces rares sur place dans le centre de PARIS.

Answer (score 1):

In the figurative sense, *monnayer* (with an *a*, not *e*) means "getting paid for something". Almost inevitably this invokes the idea of some sort of corruption or debasement (of what is being sold). I've hardly ever seen *monnayage* used for those figurative senses (though it probably occurred somewhere).

Comment: I've hardly ever seen *monnayage* used in a non figurative sense :-)